# How to make smooth animation in toggleClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make smooth animation, when I use Jquery toggleClass method? I used css transitions, but there is a delay, but there is no smoothness.

```
.paragraph {
  height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

[Link to my code](https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/NMwygw)

Comment: Try slidetoggle

Comment: or see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025292/smooth-out-this-jquery-toggle-animation

Comment: Something [like this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjPKre)?

Comment: @Alon Eitan, thank you. Exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's toggleClass to add transition effects: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dxjsqess/)

```
$('.i-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).prev('.paragraph').toggleClass("paragraph_all", 1000);

  if ($(this).prev('.paragraph').hasClass('paragraph_all')) {
    $(this).text('Show');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Hide');
  }
});
```

Make sure you also add the jQuery UI link: `https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js`

And here is the [documentation & demo](http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's right, but I don't use jquery ui.

Comment: Hey @Dan, the jQuery UI link is separate from the standard jQuery link and just makes animations such as this possible. You add both of them. Can you accept my answer? :)